# How exactly do I find the exact value of $\tan(-15^{\circ})$?

Tags: trigonometry

Here, I tried to simplify it to something like this:
$$\frac{-1+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}}{1+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}}$$

But, the value seems too large.  Any help on simplifying this?

Comment: Is that supposed to be $\tan(15^\circ)?$  The usual default is radians, but the number $15$ makes me suspect degrees.

Comment: Ross, it is in degrees.

Comment: The result you obtained is correct. Just follow @RossMillikan's answer and you will be able to simplify it further.

Answer (score 4):

$$\tan (-15)=-\tan (\frac {30}{2}) $$

$$\tan (30)=\frac {2\tan (15)}{1-\tan^2 (15)} $$
$$=\frac {1}{\sqrt {3}} $$

let $x=\tan (15) >0$ and
$a=\tan (30) $. then

$$2x=(1-x^2)a $$
or
$$ax^2+2x-a=0$$
and
$$x=\frac {-1+\sqrt {1+a^2}}{a} $$

$$=(-1+\frac {2}{\sqrt {3}} )\sqrt {3} $$
$$=2-\sqrt {3} $$
finally
$$\tan (-15)=\sqrt {3}-2$$

Answer (score 2):

You need to know a few things to do this. First of all, you need the fact that the tangent function is odd, or that
$$\tan(-x)=-\tan(x)$$
You also need the half-angle formula:
$$\tan(\frac{\theta}{2})=\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos\theta}{1+\cos\theta}}$$
Now you can say that
$$\tan(-15)=-\tan(15)$$
$$\tan(-15)=-\tan(\frac{30}{2})$$
$$\tan(-15)=-\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos30}{1+\cos30}}$$
The cosine of $30$ is well-known to be $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$, so now we can say that
$$\tan(-15)=-\sqrt{\frac{1-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}{1+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}}$$
Now we simplify:
$$\tan(-15)=-\sqrt{\frac{2-\sqrt{3}}{2+\sqrt{3}}}$$
And that's your exact value (though it may still be simplifiable).

Comment: Yes, it is still simplifiable.

Comment: $$\frac{2-\sqrt{3}}{2+\sqrt{3}}=\frac{4-2\sqrt{3}}{4+2\sqrt{3}}=\frac{(1-\sqrt{3})^2}{(1+\sqrt{3})^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

You can multiply numerator and denominator by the conjugate of the denominator, here $1-\frac {\sqrt 3}3$.  That makes the denominator $1^2-(\frac {\sqrt 3}3)^2=\frac 23$ which helps.

Added:
$$\left(-1+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\right) \left(1-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\right) =-1 \cdot 1 +\frac {\sqrt 3}3\cdot 1 +(-1)(-\frac{\sqrt 3}3)-\frac {\sqrt 3}3\cdot \frac {\sqrt 3}3
\\=-1 +\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{3}-\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\right)^2\\
=-1+\frac{2\sqrt 3}3-\frac 13\\
=\frac 23(\sqrt 3-2)$$

Comment: wait.... when this happens, what does the numerator equal?

Comment: @JSBach Just expand this:
$$\left(-1+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\right) \left(1-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\right)=-1+\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{3}-\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\right)^2=\cdots$$
Combining the results of the numerator and denominator, you should get the same answer provided by Salahamam.

Comment: All right; I have tried this solution.  I multiplied by the conjugate, and it seems that I am getting 2.  I'm not sure why, since I see the answer is sqrt(3)-2

Comment: From projectilemotion's comment, the whole expression is $\frac 32(-1+\frac {2\sqrt 3}3-\frac 13)=\sqrt 3-2$

Comment: Oh, my bad.  That cleared it up.  Thank you both.

Comment: Sorry for all the questions, but how exactly did projectilemotion get (2*sqrt(3))/3?  I thought you'd just be squaring  the latter.

Comment: It is the cross term in the multiplication.  The expressions inside the parentheses on the left are negatives of each other, so the result is minus the square of either.

Comment: Ross, can you please explain further? I don't understand what you mean by "result is minus the square of either."  I still don't get how it translate into the above result.

Comment: It is just expanding the product.  I added it in the main answer